# Display Details Using React Router

Tags: reactjs

I have a router to display individual class detail. The code works on my local computer URL for the detail view, http://localhost:3000/course/16623, but it has a 404 error when I deploy the code to the web server, https://url/course/16623. How to resolve this issue? Thanks. Below is my code:

Routing.js

```
 const Routing = () => (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/course/:CLASS_NBR' component={Bookmark} />
      <Route  path="/" component={App} />
    </Switch>
     </>
    );
    export default Routing;
```

CourseDetail.js

```
...
 <Link  to={{ pathname: '/course/'+course.CLASS_NBR

            }}
            target="_blank"
                        key={course.ID}>
                        View this course
                    </Link>
```

Bookmark.js

```
 class Bookmark extends Component {
        state={
           CLASS_NBR: this.props.match.params.id, 
          course:[]
        };

        componentDidMount(){
           const {CLASS_NBR} = this.props.match.params.CLASS_NBR ;
            this.runSearch();
         }

         runSearch=async()=>{

           const response= await axios.get('url/api/get',
           {
              params: {
              CLASS_NBR: this.props.match.params.CLASS_NBR
              }
           })
           this.setState({course: response.data});
         }
      render(){
          if (!this.state.course){
              return <div>No record found</div>
          }

          const course =this.state.course;

          return (

             <div>
             <h4>
              {course["SUBJECT"]} {course["CATALOG_NBR"]} - {course["COURSE_DESCR"]}  
              </h4>

            </div>

      );
      }   
      };

    export default Bookmark;
```

Comment: This is probably a webserver issue. Your webserver needs to serve the same index page for all urls. See https://gist.github.com/ywwwtseng/63c36ccb58a25a09f7096bbb602ac1de for instance, this must be explained in the react documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

React is running as a single page app so you need to route all requests to index.html.

Add this to your `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

As a bonus, if you want to build a 404 page you can configure it with [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match).

Comment: Thanks. But we have Windows IIS web server. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using hash routing. See this post https://muffinman.io/react-router-subfolder-on-server/.